# `npm run test` failed but `ng test` run successful

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-cli, node-modules

I don't know why `ng test` is run successful, and `npm run test` is failed

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fe-patient",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "commit": "git cz",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
...
```

npm run test should do the same with ng test...

What i have tried and the issue still exists:

- npm cache clean --force
- rm -rf node_modules
- rm -rf package-lock.json
- npm install
- npm run test

Angular 12+, npm 6.14.8, ionic 5+

Comment: can you share the logs when trying `npm run test`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally find the root cause...

Current we haven't written any UT (spec files), so we delete all the spec files.

`ng test` will show successful if there is 0 spec file,

`npm run test` will give an error if there is 0 spec file.

**Update Better solution:**

Update config in karma.conf.js will also work:

```
failOnEmptyTestSuite: false,
```